Securely access Google Apps Script deployed as web app from external server
I have a Google Apps Script project that I want to deploy as a web app. This web app is supposed to be called from an external c# web site, for internal/company use only. Basically a server-to-server call.
In this c# website, I already am calling Google Drive and Sheets API using a service account I created in Google Cloud console.
My problem is that in order for me to call the web app I created from this c# website, I need to deploy it with Who has access set to 'Anyone'.
This of course is a security issue because the web app functions can be executed by anyone who has the link.
I've been doing a lot of research and experimenting and still have not figured out how to make the web app secure, with using a service account to call it.
I've even asked Gemini and it has been persistent that I can use OAuth2 with grant type = 'client_credential'. I never got this to work, or I'm implementing it incorrectly.
This requirement is not unique in my case, and I assume there are already some if not a lot of systems out there with this implementation.
So the question is:
How do I make a Google Apps Scripts web app, that is not available publicly but can be called securely from an external website without OAuth2 (or using OAuth2 without the user interaction)?
Thanks in advance!

About I need to deploy it with Who has access set to 'Anyone'., in this case, I think that the Web Apps is not required to be accessed without the access token. So, the service account is not required to be used. If you want to make the specific users access Web Apps in this condition, how about using a custom key in the query parameter or the request body? Or, for example, if you can set "Who has access to the app" as Anyone within MY-DOMAIN or Anyone with Google account, the access token is required to be used to access Web Apps. In this case, the service account can be used.

Thanks @Tanaike. But as I understand it, a service account is not part of my domain, so it won't work when set to 'Anyone within my domain'. I haven't tried with 'Anyone with Google account'. But still if that works, practically everyone has a Google account :-D, so it won't really be secure.

Thank you for replying. About a service account is not part of my domain, so it won't work when set to 'Anyone within my domain'. I haven't tried with 'Anyone with Google account'., I couldn't notice it from your question. I apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, I think that it is required to permit to access the service account by the administrator of Google Workspace. How about this?

About I haven't tried with 'Anyone with Google account'. But still if that works, practically everyone has a Google account :-D, so it won't really be secure., in this case, how about using a custom key in the query parameter and the request body?

Thanks again @Tanaike for taking time for this, btw I don't see anything wrong with your English skills. I'm not a native English speaker myself. I have tried 'Anyone with a Google account' and this does not work (or I'm doing it wrong).  I'll try as you suggested having some sort of key. I guess Google should make it easier for service accounts to work with in-house systems like adding an option 'Any of my service accounts'. Maybe more devs will be making enterprise then.

Thank you for replying. About I'll try as you suggested having some sort of key., I think that this is one of several approaches. By the way, about I haven't tried with 'Anyone with Google account'. But still if that works, practically everyone has a Google account :-D, so it won't really be secure., I forgot to add more information. In the case of Anyone with Google account, all Google users cannot access the Web Apps.

Only the Google users including the service account shared with the Google Apps Script project of the Web Apps can access Web Apps. So, for example, only if you share the Google Apps Script project of the Web Apps with the email of the service account, only the service account can access your Web Apps. Is this closed to your expected result?

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but sharing only applies to access to the code itself, right? It is not applied when it is deployed. The 'Who has access' setting takes over the permission.

Thank you for replying. About sharing only applies to access to the code itself, right?, I think that it's yes.

Currently I implemented a token in the querystring, in the absense of a more ideal implementation. I'll keep this open in case some one comes up with it. Thanks again @Tanaike for taking the time!
